# Non-blocking web service client using AsyncHTTPConduit CXF (JAVA)

Tags: java, web-services, nonblocking

I am trying to create a non I/O blocking web service client in JAVA. I am using the AsyncHTTPConduit from CXF.

However, when there are 2 request, it seems it will create a new connection instead of reuse it. It will create new dynamic port to send web service.

Source Code:
    public Dispatch getDispatcher(String alias, String namespace, String wsdlLocation, String serviceName, String portName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

```
    Dispatch<Source> dispatcher = getDispatcher(wsdlLocation, namespace, serviceName, portName);

    // Create our custom SSLSocketFactory
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactoryGenerator(alias, keyStoreLocation, trustStoreLocation)
            .getSSLSocketFactory();

    Client client = ((org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl) dispatcher).getClient();
    client.getRequestContext().put("use.async.http.conduit", true);
    client.getRequestContext().put(AsyncHTTPConduit.USE_ASYNC, AsyncHTTPConduitFactory.UseAsyncPolicy.ALWAYS);
    client.getRequestContext().put("org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.MAX_CONNECTIONS", 501);
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    System.out.println("testtest: "+conduit.getClass().getName());
    TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
    tlsClientParameters.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
    conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);
    conduit.getClient().setConnection(ConnectionType.KEEP_ALIVE); 
    conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(10000000L);

    return dispatcher;
}
```

Call dispatcher to send web service:

```
Source requestSource = (new StreamSource(new StringReader(request)));
    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
    Future<?> f = dispatch.invokeAsync(requestSource, handler);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    MyHandler handler2 = new MyHandler();
    Source requestSource2 = (new StreamSource(new StringReader(request)));
    Future<?> f2 = dispatch.invokeAsync(requestSource2, handler2);
```

log file:

08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 127.0.0.1:13629<->127.0.0.1:8080[ACTIVE][rw:w]: 542 bytes written
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /fghet/sd/qqwsdfdd?wsdl HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache CXF 3.1.4.redhat-1[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 323[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "AAAAAAA003YYYYYYYY"
08:24:35.491 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-0 127.0.0.1:13629<->127.0.0.1:8080[ACTIVE][r:w]: Event cleared [w]
08:24:38.468 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 2] start execution
08:24:38.469 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
08:24:38.469 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
08:24:38.469 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 2] Request connection for {}->http://localhost:8080
08:24:38.469 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 1000; total allocated: 1 of 5000]
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: http-outgoing-1][route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 1000; total allocated: 2 of 5000]
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - [exchange: 2] Connection allocated: CPoolProxy{http-outgoing-1 [ACTIVE]}
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-1 127.0.0.1:13630<->127.0.0.1:8080[ACTIVE][r:]: Set attribute http.nio.exchange-handler
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-1 127.0.0.1:13630<->127.0.0.1:8080[ACTIVE][rw:]: Event set [w]
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-1 127.0.0.1:13630<->127.0.0.1:8080[ACTIVE][rw:]: Set timeout 0
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch - http-outgoing-1 [ACTIVE]: Connected
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl - http-outgoing-1 127.0.0.1:13630<->127.0.0.1:8080[ACTIVE][rw:]: Set attribute http.nio.http-exchange-state
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient - Start connection routing
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - Connection route established
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - [exchange: 2] Attempt 1 to execute request
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
08:24:38.470 [I/O dispatcher 2] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED